# Microsoft YARN: What is its equivalent of access control of IPs listed in a file in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

With Nginx, the following configs can be added to a `server` block to implement the access control of the incoming IPs

```
        include /etc/nginx/hosts-allowed/allowed-ip.conf;
        deny all;
```

and an example of the `allowed-ips.conf`:

```
allow 113.52.247.250;
allow 175.52.109.236;
allow 66.52.30.191;
```

After that, one can update the conf file and reload the Nginx service to apply an new access control.

With YARN, one source I found close to this is https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/authn-authz.html. However, it doesn't seems matchable to the need.

Any ideas?